# How do I pass information from js onclick event to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am not sure how to ask this on google, tried few times but I did not find what I've been looking for.

I will have a table with users on the admin panel, admins will be able to click users names for more info.

What I do not know how to do is how to get the ID of the user that was clicked in the table so I can show it inside the modal that will pop up?

And also how to create a dynamic link like mysite.com/index.php?userprofile-61 or something like that where 61 is the id of the user.
I tried using header but that will refresh the page.. I just want the modal to show along with that dynamic ID.

So:

- I do not know how to get the ID of a user when clicked in a table.
- I do not know how to make a dynamic URL to show the modal without refreshing the page.

Sorry if this looks stupid but I tried searching, did not find anything to help me..

Comment: Are you actively trying to avoid using cookies?

Comment: didi you entered your question on google and clicked on the third result??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know how to get the ID of a user when clicked in a table.

This depends on your table. Maybe you can find the id in some html attribute

> I do not know how to make a dynamic URL to show the modal without refreshing the page.

This can be achieved using a lot of different methods. The easiest is using the query params. Given a php file, for instance: `myaddress.com/index.php` you can pass parameters using this notation: `myaddress.com/index.php?id=myid`. Then in your index php you can retrieve  it like this: `$id = $_GET["id"];`. Note that you should add some security checks.

Comment: Can you give me few examples of security checks?

Comment: @Andrei here you can check some of them: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php